# 2D Rotation formula from Book doesn't work

Tags: geometry

I haven't had to do much Math in my code since leaving the university, so I decided to do a refresher, using the book called "Mathematics and Physics for Programmers".

The book says, on page 113, that to rotate a point around the origin, the formula is (angles are in radian):

```
new_x = sqrt(x*x + y*y) * cos(alpha - atan(y,x))
new_y = sqrt(x*x + y*y) * sin(alpha - atan(y,x))
```

Sounds simple, but is different from all the examples I saw in Google about rotating. When Googling, it seems that everyone else does it like this:

```
new_x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
new_y = y * cos(angle) + x * sin(angle)
```

(Which seems to be giving correct results)

Now my problem is that it doesn't work, and I'd like to know why. My assumption is that using an angle (alpha) near 0.0, there should be hardly any changes in the coordinates, but what I get is that the sign of some coordinate components are negated.

For example, (-3.333, -1.667) turns to (-3.333, 1.667) with a rotation of 0.004 radian.

The Java code looks like this:

```
double h = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
double atanyx = atan2(y,x);
double angle = alpha - atanyx;
return new Point(h*cos(angle), h*sin(angle));
```

So what is the problem? Is the formula wrong in that book? If not, why is it different from what everyone else does? And why is my Java implementation not working as expected? My expectation being that an angle near 0 would cause negligible changes in the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in the book is wrong. It should be:

```
new_x = sqrt(x*x + y*y) * cos(atan(y,x) + alpha)
new_y = sqrt(x*x + y*y) * sin(atan(y,x) + alpha)
```

For what it's worth, the second formula you have above is both faster and much more commonly used.

Comment: Thanks! Your corrected version works. I doubted my code, as one normally expects such books to have been proof-read ...